# Secuencia de Fibonacci con iteradores

Tags: python, python-3.7

el siguiente código muestra la secuencia de Fibonacci desarrollado con un iterador que devuelve, uno por uno y en orden ascendente, los n primeros números de la secuencia de Fibonacci, siendo n un número entero positivo que se le pasa como parámetro. El problema es que me lanza un error diciendo que el atributo no existe y este, está definido el método **next**

**Ejemplos:**

for s in Fibonacci(5):
   print(s)

**Output:**
0
1
1
2
3

for s in Fibonacci(10):
   print(s)

**Output:**
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34

```
class Fibonacci:
    """Método cálculo de la secuencia de Fibonacci mediante iterador"""

    def __init__(self, n):
        """Inicialización de atributos"""
        if type(n) == int and n > 0:
            self.__n = n
        else:
            raise ValueError("Debe ser un número positivo")

    def __iter__(self):
        self.current = self.step
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.count == 0:
            self.count += 1
            return 0
        elif self.count < self.n:
            result = self.start + self.step
            self.count += 1
            self.step = self.start
            self.start = result
            return result
        else:
            raise StopIteration

for i in Fibonacci(5):
   print(i)
```

Comment: En `__next__`, estás usando `self.start` y `self.step` antes de estar definidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El atributo debe definirse en el constructor, de todos modos seguía sin funcionar, tuve que hacer varias modificaciones.

```
class Fibonacci:
    def __init__(self, end):

        if type(end) == int and end > 0:
            self.end = end
            self.n = 0
            self.start = 1
            self.step = 0
        else:
            raise ValueError("Debe ser un número positivo")

    def __iter__(self):
        self.n = 0
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.n < self.end:
            self.start, self.step = self.step, self.start + self.step
            self.n += 1
            return self.start
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Un par de matizaciones: para comprobar el tipo se debe usar mejor `isinstance(end, int)`. Por otro lado, `__iter__` no debería _resetear_ el iterador.